# Launch words to my ".profile" not executing

Tags: bash, alias, .profile

I am trying to add launch words to my profile, however I am receiving `"hstart: command not found"`

```
sudo vi ~/.profile
alias hstart="$HOME/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/sbin/start-dfs.sh;$HOME/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/sbin/start-yarn.sh"
alias hstop="$HOME/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/sbin/stop-yarn.sh;$HOME/.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/sbin/stop-dfs.sh"
```

Location of the `.sh` files:

```
./.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/sbin

find -iname "start-dfs.sh"
./.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/libexec/sbin/start-dfs.sh
./.linuxbrew/Cellar/hadoop/2.7.3/sbin/start-dfs.sh
```

Comment: Why are you editing `~/.profil`? Shouldn't it be `~/.profile`? Did you make a typo? You also don't need `sudo` to edit `~/.profile`.

Comment: yes it was a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Points:

- By doing `sudo vi ~/.profile`, you have opened and edited your `.profile` i.e. `"$HOME"/.profile` as `root`, this is because shell does tilde (`~`) expansion first, so `sudo vi` gets the full path to the file. The inside `$HOME` expansion would depend on the calling user.
- `~/.profile` is only read for login shell (given `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login` does not exist), not for *any* interactive shell, `~/.bashrc` is read for any interactive shell session

So, you need to put the `alias` definitions in your `~/.profile` (just do `vi ~/.profile`, drop `sudo`), and to get the definitions in the current session `source` the `~/.profile` file by `source ~/.profile`. IMO, you would be better off putting the definitions in `~/.bashrc`.

---

The default `~/.bashrc` of Ubuntu has:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

so you can put the `alias` definitions in `~/.bash_aliases` too, just to keep them separate and easily maintainable.

Comment: Or maybe put them in `~/.bash_aliases`?

Comment: @edwinksl Good point, added.

Comment: When using `sudo`, the `~` still expands to the invoking user's home directory. I think this is because the shell expands that before invoking `sudo`. Try `sudo ls -d ~` to test.

Comment: @ByteCommander I stand corrected, forgot about the tilde expansion. Edited, thanks.